# KML polygon not appearing Google Fusion Tables

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables, qgis

I'm trying to display KML polygons of all Canadian provinces and territories on Google Fusion Tables for use in an interactive map I'm making. However, when I upload the KML file containing the polygons, Nunavut appears as incomplete (missing pieces of the polygon on many islands, large gap on mainland border with Northwest Territories). As far as I can tell this is not the case with any of the other 13 regions. It is especially strange because when I open the same KML file in QGIS, all regions appear as complete.

You can view the map here: [https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1KaUE7sZWdA2PtsOV2tYHQ_qCaQA0kTGuERwfZTd_#map:id=3](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1KaUE7sZWdA2PtsOV2tYHQ_qCaQA0kTGuERwfZTd_#map%3aid=3).

At first I thought that since Nunavut is in the bottom row of my table, the table may have just reached a limit and Fusion Tables just stopped loading it there. So, I went back to QGIS, isolated Nunavut, and simplified the geometries (which, as I understand, cuts down the number of lat/long points contained in the file). Then I uploaded that Nunavut file to my fusion tables and found that the same problem occurred. You can view that map here: [https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1s-aHA-rOeW8TfsOI4Ef-3rFJ0fnn_SjjIG-CDed8#map:id=3](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1s-aHA-rOeW8TfsOI4Ef-3rFJ0fnn_SjjIG-CDed8#map%3aid=3).

Even weirder, when I use other files from StatCan (all the shp files I've downloaded/converted into KML have been from here the Canadian government's statcan website), such as Census Divisions or Census Subdivisions, Nunavut always appears incomplete (and is the only province to do so).

I've tried making the conversions both in QGIS and using ogr2ogr to no avail. The Nunavut polygon always looks the same.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

-A

Comment: Do you have the original KML online somewhere?  The FusionTable contains a MultiGeometry with 7 Polygons, there is a limitation in FusionTables on MultiGeometries where it only displays the 10 most significant regions.  You may be running into one of the [other limitations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) like this one `A cell of data in Fusion Tables supports a maximum of 1 million characters; it may sometimes be necessary to reduce the precision of coordinates or simplify polygon or line descriptions.`, you might need multiple rows for that.

Comment: Looks like the [Natural Earth Data set in FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=76.053085&lng=-77.787010&zoom=3&type=m&tableid=19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA&tablequery=SELECT%20%27name_0%27%2C%20%27name_1%27%2C%20%27kml_4326%27&tablewhere=%27name_0%27%20%3D%20%27Canada%27%20and%20%27name_1%27%20%3D%20%27Nunavut%27) does a little better, I think that table got relief from some of the restriction, you may be able to use that.